# JQuery Tabs & cookie plugins - 2 tabs highlighted

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jquery with tabs plugin and the cookie plugin to remember the previously selected tab.
However, when the page is opened again it successfully remembers the last tab selected but then when a new tab is chosen both the new and the old one are highlighted.
When another is selected then it just highlights that one.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ cookie: { name: 'selectedTab', expires: 300 }});
```

Can anyone suggest a solution please?
Thanks

Comment: I, and likely others, would need to see more of your code to address this, or even better, if you can post a link to a sample of it somewhere online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that I needed the latest version of jquery installed.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#cookie

Have you gone through this ?

Comment: Hi,yes - I've been pouring over this (and other googled stuff) for hours. Are you indicating there is in fact something specific there which will help me?

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, I would need to see more of you code to be sure, but my initial guess would be that you're probably highlighting the selected tabs using a CSS class.  You have to make sure that you are also REMOVING that class from anywhere that it's already applied before applying it.

Similar to this:

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
    // First remove your highlight class from any tabs already highlighted
    $('.selectedTabHighlightClass').removeClass('selectedTabHighlightClass');

    // Then add the class to the newly selected tab
    $(this).addClass('selectedTabHighlightClass');  
});
```

Comment: OK, I'll look at this. We are having a "bit of weather" here, so will look tomorrow or I'll be stranded here all night!